# How to move android Navigation Bar to the right side of the display

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationbar

I need to move the android Navigation Bar from the bottom of the display to the right side of the display.

The android app I'm working on requires the user to touch the bottom of the screen often, so I'd like to move the navigation bar to the right side of the screen.  I believe this is possible, as I've seen it done in several games. The attached image shows what I'd like to achieve; when the user swipes from the bottom or top, the android bars appear at the top and RIGHT side, as opposed to the top and BOTTOM.

[image]

I've read through a lot of existing similar posts, and have tried the suggested answers, however they seem to instruct how to move a navigation DRAWER (ie a new "bar" implemented by the app) to the right side, as opposed to the BAR itself;  I believe these are two different things.
Further, the information on android developer (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) suggests that the bar cannot be moved, it can only be temporarily hidden.  If that's the case though, how are the app's such as the one in the image doing it?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you ever tried it on design preview to make a landscape orientation?

Comment: the orientation of the above shown app will be landscape in manifest.

Comment: I should have noted that my app needs to be in the portrait orientation, so the attached image is perhaps a bad example.

Comment: *I believe this is possible, as I've seen it done in several games* can you name/show some? I have never seen or heard of this behavior

Comment: My apologies all;  this may have been wishful thinking, along with some confusion  regarding drawers, on my part.  After looking at the other apps I've seen with the bars on the top and right side again, they were in fact all in landscape mode.   Too bad...  the "sticky immersive" mode referenced here (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) offers some hope for gesturing from the bottom of the screen while in portrait, but I'll likely need to redesign the layout of my app considerably.